# Book about dystopian future, assassins, crime

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

In this book a boy aged 14, very intelligent, gets recruited into a secret assassination group. He is very poor and is promised a new life but he must never go back to his old one. He then has to train on a secret island or die on another planet. He then becomes an assassin, but struggles with the morality of killing. Meanwhile, an ex cop has stumbled upon the organization. Also, the organization’s top assassin figures out that she will be killed after she gains her freedom.